# Overriding Boostrap Box-Sizing Universal Selector

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, primefaces

Bootstrap defines the following:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

:after, :before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box
}
```

Unfortunately this messes up my radio buttons which I am using from another theme (Java Primefaces):

[image]

```
    <div class="ui-radiobutton ui-widget">
   <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
      <input id="form:quest:0:questionId:0" name="form:quest:0:questionId" type="radio" value="Yes" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:'form:quest:0:questionId',e:'valueChange',p:'form:quest:0:questionId',u:'form:quest:0:msgQuestion'});" checked="checked" />
   </div>
   <div class="ui-radiobutton-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-state-active">
      <span class="ui-radiobutton-icon ui-icon ui-icon-bullet" />
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to fix this for just the radio button class (.ui-radiobutton-icon) but the universal selector seems to always override even when I use !important to reset the style to content-box. 
e.g.

```
.ui-radiobutton-icon, .ui-radiobutton-icon:before, .ui-radiobutton-icon:after
    {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box !important;
    box-sizing: content-box !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick. I was targetting the wrong element.

```
   .ui-radiobutton-box
        {
        -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You just have to make sure your ui CSS (Java Primefaces) will load **AFTER** the bootstrap CSS.

Comment: It is loading after...but it doesn't override. I am guessing because the universal selector overrides even though it loads before.